# Permission Denied while Installing Docker Machine in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am new in Ubuntu and I was trying to install Docker Machine in my Ubuntu.

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.7.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-machine && \ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

When I try this code it Shows the Error

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-machine: Permission denied
```

Please help me to solve the problem. Also I was just try with **Sudo**. But it shows the same problem. Please help.
 Thank you.

Comment: @nole I tried. But it shows the same error. Thanks.

Comment: and instead of curl -l with sudo wget

Comment: @nole not fixed. same error.

Comment: try with other version: curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.8.0-rc2/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine && \
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine

Comment: @nole No. The problem is not fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117591/discussion-between-nole-and-melbin-mathai).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue, fixed by running the following:

```
sudo -i

curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.7.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-machine && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

After that docker-machine appears in the `/usr/local/bin/`, but somehow  chmod from the command above still don't work. To fix that type in the new terminal:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine

curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.7.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-machine && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

and the docker-machine will be installed.

Comment: it worked! it is strange that in the original installation instructions, the `chmod` command is not included: https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/

Answer (score 1):

[FOR MAC]

hi , i am pretty new to MAC & DOCKER.
finally i resolved the issue, shared here :)

this issue comes cause u don't have permission in that directory.
so the simplest way is to just add permission to there.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
```

[image]

Credit : https://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2016/07/30/docker-usrlocalbindocker-machine-permission-denied/

Answer (score 0):

Also could help deleting old `.docker` directory:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.docker/
```

Otherwise you could receive the same problem with permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same error. In the default website of [Docker-machine install on MacOS](https://docker-docs.netlify.app/machine/install-machine/#install-machine-directly), type the commands separately instead of clubbing them together; like this:

```html
base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.14.0

curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine

chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

Answer (score 0):

`curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_TOKEN" "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/images"`

I got this suggestion from Chat-GPT and it worked! Just find the available images from digital ocean so that you can use the same while creating the docker machine

`docker-machine create --driver digitalocean --digitalocean-access-token YOUR_API_TOKEN --digitalocean-image 118699135 vidly`